# Calling circle function from another function in Python 3.6 Zelle Graphics

Tags: python, function, loops, zelle-graphics

I have looked through all questions on here pertaining to circles and python and calling functions, nothing has helped me. I also can not use turtle, so please don't suggest that. Thank you!

I am trying to create a program that draws concentric circles with different colors and radiuses (to make a target-like image), but the drawCircle function needs to be called from main() and it has to have the specific parameters. I am able to run these functions separately, but not together. The graphics window shows up with the title and set background color, but no circles. Is there an error in the way I'm calling the drawCircle function?

```
 from graphics import *

def drawCircle(win,centerPoint,radius,color):
    circ = Circle(centerPoint,radius)
    circ.setFill(color)
    circ.setOutline(color)
    circ.draw(win)



def main():
    win = GraphWin("Target", 600, 600)
    win.setCoords(-6,-6,6,6)
    win.setBackground("brown")
    centerPoint = Point(300, 300)
    for i in range(6):
        W = drawCircle(win,centerPoint,250,"white")
        Bk = drawCircle(win,centerPoint,200,"black")
        Bl = drawCircle(win,centerPoint,150,"dark blue")
        R = drawCircle(win,centerPoint,100,"dark red")
        Y = drawCircle(win,centerPoint,50,"yellow")
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
win.setCoords(-6, -6, 6, 6)
```

You've redefined the window's coordinates to go from -6 to 6 and then draw a circle at 300, 300 -- putting it outside the window.  Comment out the above line and see how much better the result is.

Your `for i in range(6):` loop is also questionable as it keeps redrawing the same thing.  As are your assignments of `W`, `Bk`, etc. since `drawCircle()` doesn't return anything.

If you really want to use the `win.setCoords(-6, -6, 6, 6)`, as it is reasonable, then you need to adjust all your other coordinates accordingly:

```
from graphics import *

def drawCircle(win, centerPoint, radius, color):
    circ = Circle(centerPoint, radius)
    circ.setFill(color)
    circ.setOutline(color)
    circ.draw(win)

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Target", 600, 600)
    win.setCoords(-6, -6, 6, 6)
    win.setBackground("brown")
    centerPoint = Point(0, 0)

    drawCircle(win, centerPoint, 5, "white")
    drawCircle(win, centerPoint, 4, "black")
    drawCircle(win, centerPoint, 3, "dark blue")
    drawCircle(win, centerPoint, 2, "dark red")
    drawCircle(win, centerPoint, 1, "yellow")

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```